# How to custom VSCode call stack dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode to debug C++ project with cmake: debug

So, when program stop at a breakpoint, the CALL STACK dialog can show call stack. But the function name which be called attaching with its parameters are always too long, so the source file name will be hide unless one enlarge this dialog by mouse.

In my case, I care more about source file name than function parameters. So I hope function parameters can be hidden, and the source file name can show.

How to make this? Thank you!